# How do I build a custom RPi kernel DEB package?

Tags: kernel, raspbian-stretch, software-compilation

I've got a couple of patches to the kernel that I want to apply and use in Raspbian. If I follow the [Kernel building guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md), I can apply the patch and get my kernel image and modules working just fine - but how can I get all that packaged up into a nice DEB package for easier installation?

I've had a look at the source for the `raspberrypi-firmware` packages, from the [APT repo](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/), and a guide on how to build DEB packages from this [Debian forum post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=228570), but can't get it to work.

How are the `raspberrypi-kernel` DEB packages actually built? All I need to do is add my own kernel to it, but can't seem to find the actual build script that produces that pacakge. I'm trying out [Adafruit's Kernel-o-Matic](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Pi-Kernel-o-Matic), but it doesn't seem to have been updated in quite some time so I don't know if that will work properly.